# Client must be authenticated to access this resource. jira rest api

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I've created a project using node module `passport-atlassian-oauth2` and i get the `accessToken` successfully. But when I do a request to create an issue I get the error

> Client must be authenticated to access this resource.

Below is my code for create issue jira api.

Could you help please?

```
var bodyData = {
    "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": "FLUX"
        },
        "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
        "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
        }
      }
    };

var baseUrl = 'https://alamrezoanul.atlassian.net';

var options = { 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: `${baseUrl}/rest/api/3/issue`, 
    data: JSON.stringify(bodyData), 
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jiraTokens.accessToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, 
    json: true };

axios(options) 
    .then((response2) => { 
        console.log("response2.data: ", response2.data); 
    }) 
    .catch((error) => { 
        console.log("error: ", error); 
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi I encountered the same issue today. You need to fetch the cloud id of `https://alamrezoanul.atlassian.net` and then instead of doing `var baseUrl = 'https://alamrezoanul.atlassian.net';` use `var baseUrl = 'https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/{cloud id}';`.

You can fetch the cloud id by doing a authenticated GET request to `https://api.atlassian.com/oauth/token/accessible-resources`.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I have fixed instead username and password use **email** and **api token** [link to generate token](https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens)
Below code I am using in my project

```
public String getEncodedAuth() {
    String username = "user@gmail.com";//enter your mail
    String auth_header = username + ":" + "<API token>";
    String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth_header.getBytes());
    return encodedAuth;
}

public void getIssue(String issueId) {
    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + getEncodedAuth())
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .pathParam("issueIdOrKey", issueId)
            .queryParam("fields", "attachment")
            .when()
            .get("https://user.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/{issueIdOrKey}");

    response.prettyPrint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the audience in your authorised tokens.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/#implementing-oauth-2-0--3lo-

Setup says:

> *audience: (required) Set this to `api.atlassian.com`.*

You may need to set to alamrezoanul.atlassian.net